# UK postcode validation and format correction tool

Tags: regex, r

I've been working on a regex-based UK postcode validation and format correction tool - with the aim of creating a list of postcodes that can be readily geocoded. The variety of postcode formats is explained [here](https://www.mrs.org.uk/pdf/postcodeformat.pdf). I have based my regex on a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164979/uk-postcode-regex-comprehensive).

My correction tool is designed to cope with a number of commonly made mistakes when a postcode is inputted in a free text format as such:

- Postcode entered in lower case
- No space between first and second half of postcode
- O instead of 0 in two key areas e.g. CH6O 8MG -> CH60 8MG & M8 OFG -> M8 0FG

I have managed this (somewhat clunky) here:

```
pc<-data.frame(postcode=c("GIR 0AA","M2 0AB","M2 OAB","M2 0ab","M1 1AA","M11AA","M60 1NW","M6O 1NW","M601NW","CR2 6XH","CR26XH","DN55 1PT","DN551PT","W1A 1HQ","W1A1HQ","w1a 1hq","EC1A 1BB","EC1A1BB"), true=c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE))

#Identify postcodes not in correct format
pc$original_validate<-grepl('^((GIR 0AA)|((([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][A-HJKSTUW])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][ABEHMNPRV-Y]))) [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))$',pc$postcode)
pc$non_pc<-ifelse(pc$original_validate ==FALSE,as.character(pc$postcode),"")

#Convert all to upper case
pc$new_pc<-toupper(pc$non_pc)

#Identify postcodes without a space and include a space
pc$non_pc2<-grepl('^((GIR 0AA)|((([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][A-HJKSTUW])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][ABEHMNPRV-Y]))) [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))$',pc$new_pc)
pc$non_pc2<-ifelse(pc$non_pc2==FALSE & pc$new_pc!="",as.character(pc$new_pc),"")
pc$new_pc2<-gsub("^((GIR 0AA)|((([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][A-HJKSTUW])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][ABEHMNPRV-Y])))))([0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})$","\\1 \\9",pc$non_pc2)
pc$non_pc<-NULL
pc$non_pc2<-NULL

#Identify postcodes containing an O instead of 0 in first half
pc$non_pc3<--grepl('^((GIR 0AA)|((([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][A-HJKSTUW])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][ABEHMNPRV-Y]))) [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))$',pc$new_pc2)
pc$non_pc3<-ifelse(pc$non_pc3==FALSE & pc$new_pc2!="",as.character(pc$new_pc2),"")
pc$new_pc3<-gsub("([A-Z][0-9][O]|[A-Z][A-Z][O]|[A-Z][A-Z][0-9][O])","\\10",pc$non_pc3)
pc$new_pc3<-gsub("O0","0",pc$new_pc3)

 #Identify postcodes containing an O instead of 0 in second half 
 pc$non_pc4<-grepl('^((GIR 0AA)|((([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][A-HJKSTUW])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][ABEHMNPRV-Y]))) [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))$',pc$new_pc3)
pc$non_pc4<-ifelse(pc$non_pc4==FALSE & pc$new_pc3!="",as.character(pc$new_pc3),"")  
 pc$new_pc4<-gsub("^((GIR 0AA)|((([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][A-HJKSTUW])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][ABEHMNPRV-Y]))))) ([O][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})$", "\\1 0\\9",pc$non_pc4)
pc$new_pc4<-gsub("0O","0",pc$new_pc4)
pc$non_pc3<-NULL
pc$non_pc4<-NULL

#Combine pc's into one column of correctly formated postcodes
pc$total<-paste(pc$postcode,pc$new_pc,pc$new_pc2,pc$new_pc3,pc$new_pc4)
pc$correct_pc<-str_extract(pc$total,"((GIR 0AA)|((([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][A-HJKSTUW])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][ABEHMNPRV-Y]))) [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))")
pc$new_pc<-NULL
pc$new_pc2<-NULL
pc$new_pc3<-NULL
pc$new_pc4<-NULL
pc$total<-NULL

#Validate
pc$correct_validate<-grepl('^((GIR 0AA)|((([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][A-HJKSTUW])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][ABEHMNPRV-Y]))) [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))$',pc$correct_pc)
```

With the results like so:

> ```
> pc
> postcode  true original_validate correct_pc correct_validate
>  GIR 0AA  TRUE              TRUE    GIR 0AA             TRUE
>   M2 0AB  TRUE              TRUE     M2 0AB             TRUE
>   M2 OAB FALSE             FALSE     M2 0AB             TRUE
>   M2 0ab FALSE             FALSE     M2 0AB             TRUE
>   M1 1AA  TRUE              TRUE     M1 1AA             TRUE
>    M11AA FALSE             FALSE     M1 1AA             TRUE
>  M60 1NW  TRUE              TRUE    M60 1NW             TRUE
>  M6O 1NW FALSE             FALSE    M60 1NW             TRUE
>   M601NW FALSE             FALSE    M60 1NW             TRUE
>  CR2 6XH  TRUE              TRUE    CR2 6XH             TRUE
>   CR26XH FALSE             FALSE    CR2 6XH             TRUE
> DN55 1PT  TRUE              TRUE   DN55 1PT             TRUE
>  DN551PT FALSE             FALSE   DN55 1PT             TRUE
>  W1A 1HQ  TRUE              TRUE    W1A 1HQ             TRUE
>   W1A1HQ FALSE             FALSE    W1A 1HQ             TRUE
>  w1a 1hq FALSE             FALSE    W1A 1HQ             TRUE
> EC1A 1BB  TRUE              TRUE   EC1A 1BB             TRUE
>  EC1A1BB FALSE             FALSE   EC1A 1BB             TRUE
> ```

Whilst this does work fine, as you can see it takes a slightly torturous way to get there! I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions about improving the efficiency of this process? It would be great to get a single function that achieves every correction; however, my function writing skills are pretty poor!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first suggestion is to write a `is_valid` function since you are using this code in quite a few places:

```
is_valid <- function(x)
   grepl('^((GIR 0AA)|((([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][A-HJKSTUW])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][ABEHMNPRV-Y]))) [0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))$', x)
```

Then, it is also a good idea to write a separate function for each of the fixes you have. It makes your code easier to test and reuse. Also, when using appropriate function names, it makes your code self-explanatory and can replace all the comments:

```
fix_case <- toupper

fix_space <- function(x)
   sub("^((GIR 0AA)|((([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][A-HJKSTUW])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][ABEHMNPRV-Y])))))([0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})$","\\1 \\9", x)

fix_zero_1 <- function(x)
   sub("([A-Z][0-9]|[A-Z][A-Z]|[A-Z][A-Z][0-9])[O]","\\10", x)

fix_zero_2 <- function(x) {
   x <- sub("^((GIR 0AA)|((([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][A-HJKSTUW])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][ABEHMNPRV-Y]))))) ([O][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})$", "\\1 0\\9", x)
   sub("0O", "0", x)
}
```

With these, your code can simplify to:

```
postcodes <- c(
  "GIR 0AA",
  "M2 0AB",
  "M2 OAB",
  "M2 0ab",
  "M1 1AA",
  "M11AA",
  "M60 1NW",
  "M6O 1NW",
  "M601NW",
  "CR2 6XH",
  "CR26XH",
  "DN55 1PT",
  "DN551PT",
  "W1A 1HQ",
  "W1A1HQ",
  "w1a 1hq",
  "EC1A 1BB",
  "EC1A1BB"
)

bg <- postcodes
bg <- ifelse(is_valid(bg), bg, fix_case(bg))
bg <- ifelse(is_valid(bg), bg, fix_space(bg))
bg <- ifelse(is_valid(bg), bg, fix_zero_1(bg))
bg <- ifelse(is_valid(bg), bg, fix_zero_2(bg))

data.frame(original   = postcodes,
           best_guess = bg,
           is_valid   = is_valid(bg))
```

Note how I am using vectors everywhere and only in the end putting the results in a data.frame. Indeed, there is arguably no need for a data.frame until you want to see the results in a nice format, at the very end. Keeping things in vectors avoid the repetitive `pc$` and the annoying conversion from character vectors to factors (what forced you to use `as.character`).

I have slightly modified your algorithm, where instead of replacing valid postcodes by `""` so they won't get affected by fixes, I am propagating a vector of valid or "best guess" codes (`bg`) via the construct:

```
bg <- ifelse(is_valid(bg), bg, som_fix(bg))
```

It is shorter this way and removes the need for the error-prone `paste()` at the end of your code.

Comment: Beautifully done, thanks! Definitely see your point over vector vs. dataframe - nearly all my work is done in dataframes, so I don't tend to think of other data structures potentially making my life easier!

Comment: Quick add on - I have been working on an extended version of your code encompassing more common mistakes (will post as answer when complete)... As I haven't seen anything like this available as a completed function my intention is to publish it somewhere like R-Bloggers for future use (code review doesn't get very high footfall) 1. would you be ok with this? 2. How do you want me to acknowledge you?

Comment: Thanks for asking, but feel free to publish however you like. There is no need to acknowledge me, or you can just say "a user on CodeReview".

Comment: Cheers! Should be a useful tool for people